# Android clang LLVM undefined errors

Tags: android, c++, terminal, clang, llvm

I rooted my android phone and installed termux and clang.
When I tried to compile this code:

`#include <android/sensor.h>
int main(){
   ASensorManager* sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();
}`

to access sensors in my phone it gives a bunch of errors like:

```
undefined reference to 'llvm::Type::getIntegerBitWidth
undefined reference to 'llvm::APFloat::IEEEHalfe
```

I compiled it on termux using clang:

```
clang++ main.cpp -o main -landroid
```

but I cant find the library Im supposed to link with or if this even works at all.